# I have a solution with two projects how can i use methods from the library type project in the winforms project?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

The first project is Class Library.
I can't just run it so i added a winforms project so i can use the Library methods and classes so i can debug the Library project.

But i can't get to the Lubrary project form the winforms.
In the winforms:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }


        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

And the Library project name is AviFile and inside it there are classes.

When i type in the timer tick event AviFile it's not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add reference to your class library project named `AviFile` in your winform project by right clicking `Reference` -> Add reference -> Select Project -> choose the dll and select OK.

Then in your Form class import the namespace saying `using AviFile;`

See [MSDN Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky(v=vs.120).aspx) on how to do that.

Comment: @RezaAghaei, that's alright but not sure how you added a link in comment though?

Comment: Comments use mini-Markdown formatting:  `[text of link](http://example.com)`.  [Learn more](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting)

Comment: @RezaAghaei, didn't had idea about the link one ... nice thanks for showing it.

Comment: You have to add a using statement to point to what you added as a reference.  (Second paragraph in his answer)

Comment: @TheLostLostit, read the answer properly and also see the link provided in answer.